# why angular-d3-charts is not working?

Tags: angular

```
**HTML:**
    <angular-d3-donut [id]="donutChartId" [data]="donutChartData"></angular-d3-donut>  
    **App.module.ts:**

    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import 'd3';
    import 'nvd3';
    import {NvD3Module} from "ng2-nvd3";
    import { DoughnutChartComponent, PieChartComponent, BarChartComponent } from 'angular-d3-charts'; // this is needed!
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        NvD3Module,
       DoughnutChartComponent, 
       PieChartComponent, 
       BarChartComponent
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
    **Index.html:**
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    **Donut chart component.ts:**


    import {Component, ValueProvider} from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {

      options: any;
      data: any;
      donutChartId:any;

      constructor() {
    }
          public donutChartData = [{
          id: 0, // number
          label: 'label name',  // string
          value: 50,  // number
          color: 'color of slice',  // string,
          iconImage: 'path of image' // string
       },{
          id: 1, // number
          label: 'label name',  // string
          value: 100,  // number
          color: 'color of slice',  // string,
          iconImage: 'path of image' // string
       }
       ]
      }
```

Now i am working in d3 chart and i installed (npm install angular-d3-charts --save).I followed each and every step they provided but i have in html page ([data]="donutChartData").The error is

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>       - Identifier 'donutChartData' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, 
>        and element references do not contain such a member
>       - Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'angular-d3-donut'.
>   1. If 'angular-d3-donut' is an Angular component and it has 'data' input, then verify that it is part of this 
>    module.
>   2. If 'angular-d3-donut' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the 
>    '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
>          don't know to solve this anyone give me some idea to work it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Inject component into `declaration` instead of `import` in `ngModule`:

```
import { DoughnutChartComponent, PieChartComponent, BarChartComponent } from 'angular-d3-charts';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DoughnutChartComponent, 
    PieChartComponent, 
    BarChartComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

you can check documentaion here: [angular-d3-charts](https://github.com/amanjain325/angular-d3-charts)

Comment: <angular-d3-donut [id]="donutChartId" [data]="donutChartData"></angular-d3-donut>

Comment: the error is Identifier 'donutChartId' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and 
 element references do not contain such a member

Comment: tq so much for ur answer

Comment: Please accept answer if it is useful for you or vote up

Comment: @AbijithAjayan can you post question along with some code that what are you trying i am unable to get it? I mean which data values, on which click function???

Comment: @Sanoj_V Actually Am trying one emi calculator function. After click the button i assigned values to d3 chart also, but its not reflecting in chart, but values are passing in console.

Comment: @AbijithAjayan here i have created demo for updating bar charts [angular-d3-bar-chart-with-random-data](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3-bar-chart-with-random-data)

Comment: @Sanoj_V Thank you for your valuable reply,.. I solved the issue with adding chart.js. I removed d3.